# Postcode and Country Match with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some difficulties to get a regex running for these cases - sorry I´m very new to regex and can´t figure it out.

The pattern looks like this:

- 12            (true)
- 123           (true)
- 1234          (true)
- 12345         (true)
- 1    a...     (false)
- 12   a...     (false)
- 123  a...     (false)
- 1234 a...     (false)
- 12345 m       (true)
- 12345 mün     (true)
- münchen 123   (false)
- mün 12345     (true)

so if combined with letters, postcode has to fullfill the max length given in the range
like `{2,5}`.

I tried with this one, but is doesn´t work like I need it:

`/^([0-9]{2,5})(\s+[^a-zA-Z]{2,})?$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

`/^([0-9]{5}\s[a-z]+)$|^([a-z]+\s[0-9]{5})$|^([0-9]{2,5})$/i` (edited after comment)

Note the OR operator:

Matches `[0-9]{5}\s[a-z]+` OR `[a-z]+\s[0-9]{5}` OR `[0-9]{2,5}`

You can add any international characters in the word match, for example: `[a-zä-üß]` but depending on the language you are using, better options could be supported.

**TESTS**
http://jsfiddle.net/zd4Qm/4/

Comment: "mün 123456789" matches the pattern, but the postcode is longer than allowed.

Comment: What about "mün 12345"? It should match but does not. :)

Comment: Read the note I've just added for international chars like ü, just replace [a-z] by [a-zä-üß]

Comment: That doesn't fix it. `/^([0-9]{2,5}\s[a-zä-üß]+)$|^([0-9]+)$/i.exec("mün 12345")` returns null.

Comment: Oh wait! I missed one case from the OP

Comment: You added a `^` to fix the first issue and that's why "mün 12345" doesn't match any more. :)

Comment: added tests for easy checking

Comment: hi to all. thx for your reply. but i need that this get false too:
abcd 1234 (false)
1234 abcd (false)
12345 abcd (true)
is this possible?
abcd 12345 (true)

Comment: I don't understand. 1234 is in the range {2,5}. Or you mean true for 2 and 5 but not for 3 and 4?

Comment: so normally i wanna check for possible ranges, like if you only put in digits the range that is accepted is min 2 digits and max 5 digits - thisi si because i´m using it with an Autocompletion plugin

and if you combine the digits with letter the max value (in this case 5) has tobe fullfiled

Comment: If min length is 2 and max is 5, then "abcd 1234" is correct. Isn't?

Comment: no - 1 (false), 12 (true), 123 (true), 1234 (true), 12345 (true), 123456 (false) # 1 a (false), 1 ab (false), 1 abcde... (false), 1234 ab.... (false), 12345 ab.... (true)

Comment: and "12 abcd" or "abcd 12"?

Comment: 12 a... || a... 12  <- false

Comment: 12345 a... || a... 12345 <- true

Comment: 1: ok (should be null)
123456789: ok (should be null)
12, 123, 1234, 12345 <- ok

Comment: If it works, remember to mark the answer as valid pressing the `V` icon

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, regular expressions are not the only answer.

```
if (there are letters in the string) {
    search for /\d{5}/
} else {
    search for /\d{2,5}/
}
```